# google actions: reprompts not showing

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to get the system to prompt if the user is silent or not entered any response. This is using actions sdk.

As per the documentation (https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/reprompts), I set the conversation object in the json as:

```
"inDialogIntents": [
    {
      "name": "actions.intent.NO_INPUT"
    }
  ]
```

Then, in the functions code I have the following:

```
app.intent('no_input', conv => {
  conv.ask('Hello');
});
```

Yet there has been no response even after waiting for a few minutes. I even tried

```
app.intent(actions.intent.NO_INPUT, conv => {
  conv.ask('Hello');
});
```

but the code has not been called. Can someone share what needs to be done to get this working? Thanks.

Comment: What device are you testing on? The NO_INPUT behavior might change between devices. The best method to test this behavior is to use No Input button on the simulator. If it still doesn't work, then we can assume there's something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more detailed version of my comment:

First of all, smartphones **DO NOT** have no-input support, as they close the mic automatically when the user doesn't say anything and they also make it visually clear. So if you're testing on a smartphone, that's the reason you're not seeing your reprompts.

As for testing of the no-input prompts, it can be rather hard to test on a Google Home. Maybe you don't have access to one or you don't want to wait awkwardly staring at your device. For these reasons we have "No Input" button in the Simulator:

[image: "No Input" button in the simulator]

You can use this button to simulate a No Input prompt. If that still doesn't solve your problem, then you can assume there's something wrong with your code.

Comment: Again thanks @Yuksel Tolun. I did not know that smartphones do not have that support (how did I miss that!). The functionality I am testing involves smartphones due to the requirement to have display facility. That begs the question, how to handle "silence" from the user on "ask"-ing? Perhaps, will try some timeout method. Thanks

Comment: If you find a reliable method, let us know :) have a nice one.

Comment: :-) I know that is gonna be a tough one to crack. Let me check if there is a way out ... in which case I will post my code.